# How to get Terragrunt to inclue top level directories

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I'm new to Terragrunt, and I've come across a bit of a situation with how it carries out caching.

This is what my file structure looks like.

```
├── monitor
│   └── files
│       └── graph
│           └── server
│               └── default
│                   └── foo.json
└── terraform
    ├── env
    │   └── stage
    │       └── cluster
    │           ├── provider.tf
    │           └── terragrunt.hcl
    ├── moduleConfig
    │   └── cluster
    │       ├── backend.tf
    │       ├── random.tf
    │       ├── locals.tf
    │       ├── outputs.tf
    │       ├── main.tf
    │       ├── outputs.tf
    │       └── variables.tf
    └── terragrunt.hcl
```

But when I run a `terragrunt plan` and look into the `.terragrunt-cache` folder, this is what I see.

```
.terragrunt-cache/
└── KdPWtxpAXZdCe4otk2N9TY1tuQU
    └── cwMVo-pYTWr47TeiHN8aORnD8g4
        ├── env
        │   └── stage
        │       └── cluster
        │           ├── provider.tf
        │           └── terragrunt.hcl
        ├── moduleConfig
        │   └── cluster
        │       ├── backend.tf
        │       ├── random.tf
        │       ├── locals.tf
        │       ├── outputs.tf
        │       ├── main.tf
        │       ├── outputs.tf
        │       ├── provider.tf
        │       ├── terragrunt.hcl
        │       └── variables.tf
        └── terragrunt.hcl
```

This results in an undesired plan output, as there are resources in the `monitor` directory that I need.

This being said, I'm running my `terragrunt plan` from inside the `cluster` directory.

```
        ├── env
        │   └── stage
        │       └── cluster
```

which might explain the issue.

Is there a way to get Terragrunt to include the `monitor` directory as well, so that the cache contains the full tree with all the files I need?

Thanks.

#######################################################

Updated to include `path` and `source` blocks

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

```
terraform {
  source = "${path_relative_from_include()}//moduleConfig/cluster"
}
```

#######################################################

Comment: Can you share what your `include` and `source` directives look like?

Comment: I've updated the question to includes these blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `monitor` directory to get pulled in as well, you might want to take the `terragrunt.hcl` file, out of the root of the `terraform` directory and place it on the same path as the `monitor` and `terraform` directories.

And then change

```
terraform {
  source = "${path_relative_from_include()}//moduleConfig/cluster"
}
```

to read

```
terraform {
  source = "${path_relative_from_include()}//terraform/moduleConfig/cluster"
}
```

This should get the entire structure into the `.terragrunt-cache` directory.

This might make a good read, if you're curious to see how it works.

https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#path_relative_from_include